# GASでテンプレートの表をコピーしてメール本文に貼り付けたいです。

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

お世話になります。
以下のシステムをChatGPTを使用してコードを作成して業務効率化を試みています。
どなたかわかる方がおられましたらご回答を頂ければ幸いです。
以上、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

目標：Google Formが送信されたらそのデータをSSのテンプレートに入力し、**テンプレートの表をメール本文にコピペして**任意の宛先にメールを自動送付したい

結果：**太字部分**に関してテンプレートの表はコピペ出来たがフォーマットのセルの幅や罫線の表示やセル結合が崩れてしまう。

ChatGPTで作成したコードで、エラーメッセージを入れてコードの修正を試みたが、うまく行かなかった

コード（1の**太字部分**について抜粋）

```
 // スプレッドシートの範囲を取得
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:F27');
  
  // 範囲を取得したデータを配列にする
  var values = range.getValues();

  // メール本文に貼り付けるHTMLを作成
  var tableHtml = '<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;">';
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    tableHtml += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      tableHtml += '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;">' + values[i][j] + '</td>';
    }
    tableHtml += '</tr>';
  }
  tableHtml += '</table>';
```

Comment: 質問文中の "SS" とは、スプレッドシートの略でしょうか？

Comment: はい、スプレッドシートの事です。